# Perl Don't Split Last Occurrence

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get the results of the `ps -ef` command, but I'm running into one issue.

For `$cmd` it doesn't print the complete command and just splits at the space in between the command arguements.

It prints this:

```
jill 61745 8888 0 11:03 ? 00:00:04 php-fpm:
```

When it should be printing this:

```
jill 61745 8888 0 11:03 ? 00:00:04 php-fpm: pool www
```

I know a regex could accomplish this but what exactly I should be doing isn't clear to me.

```
sub refresh {
        open(OPENPIPE, "ps -ef|");
        while (<OPENPIPE>) {
                my ($uid, $pid, $ppid, $c, $stime, $tty, $time, $cmd) = split();
                print "$uid $pid $ppid $c $stime $tty $time $cmd\n";
        }
        close(OPENPIPE);
}
refresh();
```

Comment: read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)! `split` has a third argument that limits the number of resulting fields. Set it to the num of fields you want (8).

Comment: Man I should be reading it! Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)! split has a third argument that limits the number of resulting fields. Set it to the number of fields you want:

```
my @fields = split ' ', $_, 8;
```

---

Also, it is a good habit to use the 3-arg-form of `open` with lexical filehandles and error handling:

```
my @command = ("ps", "-ef");
open my $pipe, '-|', @command or die "Can't run @command: $!";
while (<$pipe>) {
  chomp;
  ...;
}
close $pipe or warn
  $! ? "Error when closing @command: $!"
     : "Return status $? from @command";
```

Comment: `split /\s+/` should almost always be `split ' '`

Answer (score 0):

With the @amon solution, this is the complete code (simpler):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $result = qx!ps -ef!;
my @fields = split /\s+/, $result, 8;
print "@fields\n";
```

Comment: You removed the error checking amon specifically added, and you reinstated the use of a shell amon specifically removed. That's not better! Talk about missing the point.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, Amon had written only the split sentence. He has edited his post after I sent mine. I'm sorry if you don't like it.